# Internal work in system made up of a ball and the earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

Assume I am considering my system to be the earth, a ball, and the gravitational interaction between them. No air resistance. Assume the ball has a nonzero initial velocity upward. I understand there would be "internal work" that is negative as the ball is slowing down. And that negative work is multiplied by $-1$ to give the change in potential energy. But why isn't that *increase* in potential energy itself considered positive work? What is so special about speed changing when it comes to counting up work?

Answer (score 0):

> But why isn't that increase in potential energy itself considered
>   positive work?

It depends on which object we choose as an object performing the work and which object we choose as the object the work is performed on.

When two objects interact, they act on each other with equal and opposite forces. Meanwhile, the point of contact, moves (if it moves) only in one direction. Therefore, we can conclude that, for any work, performed by object A on object B, there will be equal in magnitude and opposite in sign work, performed by object B on object A.

Now we can apply the above to the problem with the earth and the ball, but, to make it more straightforward, we'll replace gravity with a spring. Let's imagine that the ball is attached to one end of a horizontal spring, while the other end of the spring is attached to a wall. No gravity.

As the ball moves away from the wall, the spring performs a negative work on the ball (since its force on the ball is directed against the displacement of the ball), which reduces the kinetic energy of the ball.

At the same time, the ball performs a positive work on the spring (since its force on the spring is directed along the displacement of the spring), which increases the potential energy of the spring.

Applying the same logic to the earth-ball system is not as straightforward (e.g., the field is acting on the ball, while the ball is acting on the field), but the essence is the same.

Comment: So I believe by this logic (which I'm not objecting to by the way) I could say that the work bookkeeping for the ball could never be changed by virtue of its potential energy because that energy is not the ball's... instead it is the field's. Therefore, I am forced to only do bookkeeping on the ball's velocity when accounting for the work done on the ball (and, of course, I have to keep track of the force on the ball too): And the bookkeeping for work on the field must only be done by considering the effects on the field [of involved mass-objects changing their position]. Thoughts?

Comment: @okcapp As I've mentioned, the terminology associated with the energy of the earth-ball system and, in general, the energy of a field, is tricky (e.g., is it a potential energy of a ball, of a field, of an earth-ball system, etc.?). So, I would start with a simpler case of a ball on a spring, which, from the energy perspective, is very similar to the earth-ball system. So, if we accept the work bookkeeping process for the spring-ball system, we should be able to accept it for the earth-ball system.

Comment: @V. F.  It is not true that the work done by A on B is equal in magnitude to the work done by B on A.  The displacement don't have to be equal. This is why the work of internal forces can change the KE of the system. The net work is not zero in general.

Answer (score 0):

Work of a force is defined as that force times (vector dot product) with displacement of the material object it acts on: $\Delta W = \mathbf F \cdot \Delta \mathbf r$. Sign of this quantity is decisive. When the ball moves against the force, displacement points against the force vector, thus the product is negative, and the work is negative. Change of potential energy is irrelevant in this respect. One can define work of a force even in cases where no useful potential energy associated with that force can be defined, such as when charged particle is in static magnetic field.